# Capistrano on AWS - Always pointing to an old release

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, capistrano

I'm deploying a Laravel app to AWS using Capistrano.  It seems that if I have more than one release, the `current` symlink gets updated to the right release, but anytime i try and access the URL via the browser, it seems to hit an old release.

I can tell because a) my pushes aren't taking effect, and b) the logs are writing to the previous release's log file.

Any idea what this might be?  I'm running on Ubuntu with nginx, and have the nginx root pointing to `/path/to/current`.  I tried restarting nginx after each deployment, and that doesn't seem to help either

Comment: This discussion might be relevant: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/985#issuecomment-178927404

Comment: @MattBrictson thanks Matt, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt Brictson 's comment above led me in the right direction.  PHP-FPM holds on to some cache, so I ended up doing a graceful restart and that seemed to resolve the symlinks to the correct locations on deploy.